# Jquery Progress Bar body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to make a "False" progress bar with javascript which load the bar and when it's complete body become visible and it's work but i use a setTimeout and i want to initiate the body when the progress bar is complete ! so how i can listen progress bar complete ?

```
//PROGRESS BAR

var _start = {property: 0};
var _end = {property: 100};
jQuery(_start).animate(_end, {
    duration: 2000,
    step: function progress() {
    $('#loading').css('width', this.property + "%");        
    //console.log( 'Current percentage is ' + this.property );// You can write this to your bar
    }
});


function show() {
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#container').css({'visibility':'visible'});
    $('#bloc').css({'visibility':'visible'});
};

setTimeout(show, 2000);
```

my css : container is hidden and bloc !
Thanx a lot !!!!

Comment: When your animation is complete, shouldn't the progress bar be complete?

Comment: Is `_start` actually animating something?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(_start).animate(_end, {
    duration: 2000,
    step: function progress() {
    $('#loading').css('width', this.property + "%");        
    //console.log( 'Current percentage is ' + this.property );// You can write this to your bar
    },
    done: function () {
       show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve this ...  but here is a simple demo and source code you could use to accomplish it.

Demo [Progress bar in action](http://www.inwebson.com/demo/jpreloader-v2/)

Download [progess bar](http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/jpreloader-a-preloading-screen-to-preload-images/)